# plot lower and upper limits with two ys

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a df which is an output of `predict.lm` appended to another `df` with two columns `label` and `actual`

```
df <- data.frame(
label = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'), 
actual = c(13.9, 13.4, 13.8, 14.3, 14.2, 13.6, 14.1),
fit = c(13.8, 13.9, 14.1, 14.0, 13.9, 14.3, 14.1),
lwr = c(13.6, 13.7, 13.8, 13.8, 13.7, 14.0, 13.9),
upr = c(14.3, 14.2, 14.7, 14.3, 14.1, 14.9, 14.9)
)
```

I want to plot like this figure with the space between `lwr` and `upr` (black lines area for all points) is a transparent colour. [image: plot]

I tried this, and it give me the plot with 2 ys, but the interval are absent.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = label, y = fit)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lwr, ymax = upr)) +
  geom_line(color = "blue") +
  geom_point(aes(color = label)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = label, y = actual))
```

It gives me this plot below, but I want one like the one above with space grayed out.[image: Rplot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The desired plot can be obtained if `x` is defined as a continuous variable. One can use the row index as a continuous `x` and label it after with the desired labels using  `scale_x_continuous`.

Additionally it is a good idea to reshape the data to long format and use `key` value to set up color aesthetic:

First provide continuous x and convert to long format:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(x = row_number()) %>%
  gather(key, value, 2:5) -> df1
```

I am unsure if you desire to plot an area between `lwr` and `upr` or a line. If the area is not desired instead of `geom_ribbon` you can use `geom_linerange` which plots lines defined by `x`, `ymin` and `ymax`. You can supply the original data frame to this geom since it expects `ymin` and `ymax` to be specific columns which is not the case in `df1`.

```
ggplot(df1) +
  geom_line(aes(x = x, y = value, color = key)) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = df$label, breaks = 1:7) +
  geom_linerange(data = df %>%
                   mutate(x = row_number()), aes(x = x, ymin = lwr, ymax = upr)) +

  theme_bw()
```

[image]

To tweak the look of the whole plot you can use a custom palette  or the `get_palette` function from `ggpubr` library (since your colors resemble the `jco` color scheme) and add a bit of makeup:

```
  library(ggpubr)  

  ggplot(df1) +
    geom_line(aes(x = x, y = value, color = key), size = 1) +
    geom_point(aes(x = x, y = value, color = key), size = 2) +
    scale_x_continuous(labels = df$label, breaks = 1:7) +
    geom_linerange(data = df %>%
                     mutate(x = row_number()), aes(x = x, ymin = lwr, ymax = upr)) +
    scale_color_manual(values = get_palette(palette = "jco", 4), name = "") +
    theme_bw() +
    xlab("label") +
    ylab("Absolute") +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Or if your intention was an area depicting `lwr` and `upr`:

```
  ggplot(df1) +
    geom_ribbon(data = df %>%
                     mutate(x = row_number()), aes(x = x, ymin = lwr, ymax = upr), alpha = 0.1) +
    geom_line(aes(x = x, y = value, color = key), size = 1) +
    geom_point(aes(x = x, y = value, color = key), size = 2) +
    scale_x_continuous(labels = df$label, breaks = 1:7) +
    scale_color_manual(values = get_palette(palette = "jco", 4), name = "") +
    theme_bw() +
    xlab("label") +
    ylab("Absolute") +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]